# fetch related resource with primary resource depend on some filter in django-rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

here are my models:

```
class Ratings(BaseModel):
    resource_a = models.OneToOneField(ResourceA)
    count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    total = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    average = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.count


class UserRatings(BaseModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    score = models.IntegerField()
    rating = models.ForeignKey(Ratings)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**I want to fetch the ratings of ResourceA with rating of user who is logged-in in same API call.**

I am able to fetch ratings of ResourceA using ModelSerializer but not able to fetch rating of user who is logged in.

I tried to do it using below code in ModelSerializer of Ratings.:

```
user_rating = serializer.CharField(source='get_user_rating')
```

but I can write **get_user_rating** function only in models and I think there is no way to access request.user in model itself.

Please suggest a way so that I can fetch UserRatings of user who is logged   in along with Ratings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested serializers to get all the data in 1 api call.
Simpleest method of that is to specify depth field in Meta class of serializer.

```
Class Meta:
    depth = 1
```

But it has disadvantage that it will fetch all of the data for all foreign related fields till that depth even if you don't all of it.

You can try below approach which i like better

```
Class ResourceASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rating = RatingSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = UserRatings

Class RatingsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    resource_a = ResourceASerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Ratings

Class UserRatingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rating = RatingSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = UserRatings
```

or if you don't want to make 3 serializers:

```
Class UserRatingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    resource_a_rating = serailizers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = UserRatings
        fields = ('resource_a_rating', ) # add other fields too

    def get_resource_a_rating(self, obj):
        return obj.rating.resource_a // This data should be serializeable
```

To get the data for logged in user only over ride the get_queryset method in the view.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return UserRatings.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Perhaps you didn't read the question properly, I want to fetch UserRating of logged-in user only.

Comment: sorry about that, you need to that in the view itself. You can override get_queryset method of the view. Will update the answer will little bit of it's code.

Comment: again you are getting my question wrong, I mentioned it in bold in my question itself-
I want to fetch the ratings of ResourceA with rating of user who is logged-in in same API call.